# How to convert datetime from string format into datetime format in pyspark?

Tags: datetime, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, python-datetime

I created a dataframe using sqlContext and I have a problem with the datetime format as it is identified as string.

```
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(i[1])
df2.show
df2.printSchema()
```

Result:

```
2016-07-05T17:42:55.238544+0900
2016-07-05T17:17:38.842567+0900
2016-06-16T19:54:09.546626+0900
2016-07-05T17:27:29.227750+0900
2016-07-05T18:44:12.319332+0900

string (nullable = true)
```

Since the datetime schema is a string, I want to change it to datetime format as follows:

```
df3 =  df2.withColumn('_1', df2['_1'].cast(datetime()))
```

Here I got an error:
    TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
ndf = df2.withColumn('_1', df2['_1'].cast(DateType()))
```