# Pyspark, add colon to separate string

Tags: pyspark

I have the following string 103400 I need to write it like 10:34:00 using pyspark. let take the following column as an example

```
time
130045
230022
```

And I want it to become like this:

```
time
13:00:45
23:00:22
```

Comment: Hi can you provide a piece of code of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try with regexp_replace

```
df.withColumn("time", regexp_replace(col("time") ,  "(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})" , "$1:$2:$3" ) ).show()

+--------+
| time   |
+--------+
|13:00:45|
|23:00:22|
+--------+
```

Comment: @peter : if it solved your problem can you please upvote and mark it as answer :)